# TeamCity does not use git.exe?

Tags: git, authentication, teamcity

Does TeamCity (server) use git.exe at all? The Agent uses it, but the server does not seem to call it. I have set up wincred and Anonymous settings on the VCS but I get an error 401 on the server. I am using version 9.1.2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know for sure, but it surely uses [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) - pure Java Git library. I doubt it falls back to native git client in any scenarios.
Similarly to tools like Eclipse, it probably uses JGit exclusively.